# k-means clustering by rapidminer

Tags: cluster-computing, k-means

I'm using rapidminer to run k-means operator over 8000 files and print the output in Excel sheet. When checking the results of clustering I see some cluster empty and doesn't have any file, is this correct and normal? I give the value of k= 90 and the max run= 1000.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a mini experiment where I set all the examples in an example set to be identical. The result of this is all the examples get placed into a single cluster. I conclude from this that the behaviour is OK. I suppose it indicates that you could safely reduce the number of clusters until they all get at least one member.